# Restoring Backup from Linux MySQL 5.0.51 to Windows MySQL 5.5.17

Tags: mysql

Having issues restoring this backup. Tables are missing. Here is the command that im using.

```
mysqldump --compatible=mysql323 -u user -ppassword database > backup.sql
```

and restore

```
mysqldump -u user -ppassword database < backup.sql
```

What i want to know is there something i should be careful of when backing up from Linux MySQL 5.0.51 and restoring onto Windows MySQL 5.5.17?

Also, when i try to restore to another machine with the same version on linux. The restore flashes up with the dump header and stops. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the mysql client to restore the backup

Ex:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword database < backup.sql
```